# Creating objects from reading a file that also have dynamic arrays as their fields

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a text file that contains purchase informations and it has a structure like this

CustomerName *tab* MembershipType *tab* ShoppingDate *tab* ProductName *tab* Quantity *newline*

A customer can purchase several different objects at once so ProductName and Quantity can occur more than one time like this

```
Mary    gold    26.01.2020  Sweater 1   Jeans   2
Eve silver  20.02.2020  Sweater 2   Jeans   1
Steve   bronze  19.01.2020  Jeans   2   Sweater 3
```

I am currently trying to create an customers object from these data here is my implementation

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        Scanner shoppingList = new Scanner(new File("shoppingList.txt");
        shoppingList.useDelimiter("[\t\n]");

        Customer[] customers = new Customer[0];
        while (shoppingList.hasNext()) {
            String customerName = shoppingList.next();
            String customerMembershipType = shoppingList.next();
            String purchaseDate = shoppingList.next();

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            Date date = formatter.parse(purchaseDate);

            String[] productNameList = new String[0];
            int[] quantityList = new int[0];
            while (shoppingList.hasNext()) {
               //this is where i stuck 
            }
            Customer[] newCustomer = new Customer(customerName, customerMembershipType, purchaseDate, productNameList, quantityList);
            customers = addCustomer(customers, newCustomer);
        }
    }

        private static Customer[] addCustomer(Customer[] customers, Customer customerToAdd) {
        Customer[] newCustomers = new Customer[customers.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(customers, 0, newCustomers, 0, customers.length);
        newCustomers[newCustomers.length - 1] = customerToAdd;
        return  newCustomers;
    }

    static class Customer {
        protected String customerName;
        protected String customerMembershipType;
        protected Date purchaseDate;
        protected String[] productNameList;
        protected int[] quantityList;

        public Customer(String customerName, String customerMembershipType, Date purchaseDate, String[] productNameList, int[] quantityList) {
            this.customerName = customerName;
            this.customerMembershipType = customerMembershipType;
            this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
            this.productNameList = productNameList;
            this.quantityList = quantityList;  
    }
}
```

Basically I want to create Customer objects that can hold product name lists and their quanitites' list but since arrays are immutable and Customers can have purchase unlimited amount of product type I cant find a solution without using arrayLists however i cant use it in this assignment. What can I do at this point?

Comment: You could do something like this:List<String> productNameList = new ArrayList()<>;
List<Integer> quantiryList = new ArrayList()<>;

productNameList.add("element");
quantityList.add(1);

Answer (score 1):

I suggest instead of trying to read lines of customers AND parsing those lines, you do it separately, i.e. read lines as lines, with line per customer, and then parse lines according to your logic.

Something like the below (note I changed the Customer representation, as well as customers are now List instead of an array):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("shoppingList.txt")));

        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
            Scanner shoppingList = new Scanner(line);
            String customerName = shoppingList.next();
            String customerMembershipType = shoppingList.next();
            String purchaseDate = shoppingList.next();

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            Date date = formatter.parse(purchaseDate);

            Customer customer = new Customer(customerName, customerMembershipType, date);

            while (shoppingList.hasNext()) {
                customer.addProduct(shoppingList.next(), shoppingList.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }

    static class Customer {
        protected String customerName;
        protected String customerMembershipType;
        protected Date purchaseDate;
        protected Map<String, Integer> products = new HashMap<>();

        public Customer(String customerName, String customerMembershipType, Date purchaseDate) {
            this.customerName = customerName;
            this.customerMembershipType = customerMembershipType;
            this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
        }

        public void addProduct(String name, int qty) {
            products.put(name, qty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I can think of is to: create a new array with bigger size (Let's say double the size of old one) when the older one is full and then copy the elements to the new array.

Answer (score 0):

Reading information item by item like this has two problems: you don't know how many things the shopping list contains like you've discovered, but worse: you don't know where the shopping list ends and the data for a new customer begins.

So what I would do is read the file line by line, and split the line by the separator.

```
    while (shoppingList.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = shoppingList.nextLine();
        String[] lineItems = line.split("\t");

        String customerName = lineItems[0];
        String customerMembershipType = lineItems[1];
        String purchaseDate = lineItems[2];
        // and so on
```

Now, you know that after these first 3 items the rest of the items are product names and quantities. You can calculate how many products there are using the size of `lineItems`:

```
        int productCount = (lineItems.length - 3)/2;
        String[] productNameList = new String[productCount];
        int[] quantityList = new int[productCount];
```

Adding the values into these arrays is now simple for loop:

```
        int itemIndex = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < productCount; i++) {
            productNameList[i] = lineItems[itemIndex];
            itemIndex = itemIndex + 1; // advance to next item in the line

            quantityList[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineItems[itemIndex]);
            itemIndex = itemIndex + 1; // advance to next item in the line
        }
```